# Как убрать скольжение в Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

В Unity я столкнулся с проблемой "скольжения" персонажа после того как он перемещается. Вроде говорили мне что надо сделать так: `rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, rb.velocity.y);`. Вроде работает, но всё равно видно, что происходит то самое скольжение. Помогите если вы знаете как это сделать чтобы работало на 100%. Код передвижения смотрите ниже.

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class контроллер : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 2f;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    SpriteRenderer sr;
    public float JumpForce = 50f;



    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sr = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }



    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            sr.flipX = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            sr.flipX = false;
        }
    }



    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        else if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, rb.velocity.y);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) < 0.05)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, JumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Надо сделать так, как я написал в твоем предыдущем посте 2 дня назад, который ты удалил.

Comment: @Yaroslav я пробовал, лучше, но всё равно видно

Comment: rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
    rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно это не лучшее решение, но тебе нужно отслеживать "отжатия" (`GetKeyUp()`) кнопок передвижения, и в этом момент задавать x и z velocity равными нулю

Comment: Большое спасибо, очень помог. Только там нужно не GetKeyUp() использовать, а GetKey() так как код на передвижение срабатывает только тогда, когда ты отпускаешь клавишу (например "D"). А так реально большое спасибо за идею.